# findViewById() returns null for custom component in layout XML, not for other components

Tags: xml, android, layout

I have a `res/layout/main.xml` including these elements and others:

```
<some.package.MyCustomView android:id="@+id/foo" (some other params) />
<TextView android:id="@+id/boring" (some other params) />
```

In my Activity's onCreate, I do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView boring = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boring);
// ...find other elements...
MyCustomView foo = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.foo);
if (foo == null) { Log.d(TAG, "epic fail"); }
```

The other elements are found successfully, but `foo` comes back null. MyCustomView has a constructor `MyCustomView(Context c, AttributeSet a)` and a `Log.d(...)` at the end of that constructor appears successfully in logcat just before the "epic fail".

Why is `foo` null?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Because in the constructor, I had `super(context)` instead of `super(context, attrs)`.

Makes sense, if you don't pass in the attributes, such as the id, then the view will have no id and therefore not be findable using that id. :-)

Comment: Also, shouldn't you lines like `(MyCustomView) foo = findViewById(R.id.foo);` be `MyCustomView foo = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.foo);`?

Comment: Had the same problem, in my case I had forgotten the setContentView().. XD

Comment: There is a nice example for doing such things on vogella.com: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Comment: Also, if you have more than one constructor you will need to update all your super() methods to the correct way.

Comment: I began to have an heart attack when i saw the good 'ol findViewById() returning null...you saved my time! Thanks!

Comment: If you have both constructors (the `context` and the `context,attrs`), you must remove the `context` constructor completely - just adding the `context,attrs` constructor won't fix the problem. Also, I think this was mentioned, but to be specific, your super call must be `super(context,attrs);`, not `super(context);`. 

I had added the `attrs` argument to my constructor, but almost failed to update the super call.

Comment: This was my problem too. It's annoying that Android Studio *still* doesn't have a warning for this pretty common pitfall.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem, because in my custom view I have overridden the constructor, but invoked the super constructor without the `attrs` parameter. (That was a copy/paste mistake.)

**My previous constructor version:**

```
public TabsAndFilterRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}
```

**Now I have:**

```
public TabsAndFilterRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

**And that works!**

Answer (score 18):

Seems there is a variety of reasons. I just used "Clean..." in Eclipse to solve a similar problem. (FindViewByID had worked before and for some reason started to return null.)

Comment: apparently, the underlying problem is is that the R.java IDs somehow get broken or maybe not updated. I have noticed this not only with the IDs, but also in other cases, e.g. wrong string displayed in a TextView etc. Don't really know why this happens, though.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. My mistake was that: I wrote

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dlg_show_info, null);
        alertDlgShowInfo.setView(layout);
        TableRow trowDesc=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.trowDesc);
```

and as I used an inflater to "load" the view from an XML file, the last line was wrong. To solve it, I had to write:

```
TableRow trowDesc=(TableRow)layout.findViewById(R.id.trowDesc);
```

I wrote my solution, in case someone have the same problem.

Answer (score 11):

Same issue, but different solution: I didn't call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

BEFORE I tried to find the view as stated [here](http://www.anddev.org/solved_why_does_findviewbyid_return_null-t557.html)

Comment: I think this is the solution if you are getting an element on other view instead of the current related view.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple layout versions (depending on screen densities, SDK versions) make sure that all of them include the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In my case findViewById was returning null because my custom view looked something like this in the main XML:

```
        <com.gerfmarquez.seekbar.VerticalSeekBar  
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            />
```

and I found out that when I added the xmlns stuff it worked like this:

```
        <com.gerfmarquez.seekbar.VerticalSeekBar  
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            />
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that the `setContentView(R.layout.main)` statement call before `findViewById(...)` statement;

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was solved when I added the res folder to the Source in Java Build Path in project Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue a while back when I added a custom View via the layout XML and
then tried to attached a callback elsewhere in the application ...

I created a custom view and added it to my "layout_main.xml"

```
public class MUIComponent extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public MUIComponent (Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super ( context, attrs );
    }
    // ..
}
```

And in the main Activity I wanted to attach some callbacks and get references to the UI elements from the XML.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ...

        MUIInitializer muiInit = new MUIInitializer();
        muiInit.setupCallbacks(this);
        muiInit.intializeFields(this);
    }       
}
```

The initilizer wasn't doing anything fancy but any changes it tried to make to the custom view (MUIComponent)
or other *non-custom* UI elements simply were not appearing in the application.

```
public class MUIInitializer {

    // ...

    public void setupCallbacks ( Activity mainAct ) {


        // This does NOT work properly
        // - The object instance returned is technically an instance of my "MUICompnent" view
        //   but it is a *different* instance than the instance created and shown in the UI screen
        // - Callbacks never get triggered, changes don't appear on UI, etc.
        MUIComponent badInst = (MUIComponent) mainAct.findViewById(R.id.MUIComponent_TESTSURF);


        // ...
        // This works properly

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mainAct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View inflatedLayout = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.activity_main, null );

        MUIComponent goodInst = (MUIComponent) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.MUIComponent_TESTSURF);


        // Add callbacks
        // ...
    }

}
```

The difference between the "badInst" and "goodInst" is:

- badInst uses the Activity's findViewByID
- goodInst inflates the layout and uses the inflated layout to do the lookup

Comment: Noticed Vincent has same solution ... and his answer's shorter ... +1 his instead :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with a custom component for Wear, but is a generic piece of advice.  If you're using a Stub (such as I was using `WatchViewStub`), you can't just put the call to `findViewById()` anywhere.  Everything inside the stub must be inflated first, which doesn't just happen after `setContentView()`.  Thus, you should write something like this in order to wait for that to happen:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            myCustomViewInst = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.my_custom_view);
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a typo. I had written `android.id` (dot) instead of `android:id`. :P

Apparently there is no syntax check within my custom component xml. :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

I had layout with few children. From constructor of one them I was trying to get reference (by using context.findViewById) to other child. It wasn't working because the second child was defined further in layout.

I've resolved it like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
MyView first = findViewById(R.layout.first_child);
first.setSecondView(findViewById(R.layout.second_child));
```

It would work as well if the order of children was opposite,but I guess it generally should be done like above.

Comment: In general you should not use `findViewById` in the constructor of a `View`, but rather put the initialisation code in `OnFinishInflate`?

Answer (score 0):

The `findViewById()` method sometimes returns `null` when the root of layout has no `android:id` attribute. Eclipse wizard for generating layout xml file does not automatically generate `android:id` attribute for the root element.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the view was in the parent NOT in the view I was trying to call it in. So in the child view I had to call:

```
RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.getParent();
View view1 = relLayout.findViewById(R.id.id_relative_layout_search);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'clean' option worked for me.

In my case, the root cause is that the source code resides on a network share, and my workstation and fileserver were not synchronized correctly, and had drifted by 5 seconds. The timestamps on the files created by Eclipse are in the past (because they are assigned by the fileserver) w.r.t. the workstation's clock, causing Eclipse to resolve dependencies between generated and source files incorrectly. In this case, a 'clean' appears to work, because it forces a complete rebuild instead of an incremental build that depends on wrong timestamps.

Once I fixed the NTP settings on my workstation, the problem never occured again. Without proper NTP settings, it would happen every few hours, as the clocks drift fast.

Comment: Should add this to comment of [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5420286/1050058) above

Answer (score 0):

To add another trivial mistake to the answers to look out for:

Check that you're actually editing the right layout XML file...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem because i forgot to update the view id in all my layout folders.