# Android - Views in Custom Compound Component are not inflated (findByView returns null)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have made a Custom Component in XML, consisting of a button with an imageview stacked on top of it:

```
<myapp.widget.ClearableCaptionedButton
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ccbutton_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ccbutton_clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/ccbutton_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ccbutton_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ccbutton_button"/>
  </myapp.widget.ClearableCaptionedButton>
```

extract of java source code:

```
public class ClearableCaptionedButton extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener {
...
public ClearableCaptionedButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
// some stuff that works fine
}
..

protected void onFinishInflate() {
  super.onFinishInflate();

  mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ccbutton_button);
  mClear = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ccbutton_clear);

  mButton.setText("");  // error here: mButton == null
}
```

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-com) one. When i try to find the views inside the custom compound, findViewById returns null. But, as you can see, i already added super(context, attrs); to the constructor.
i am using the custom component directly in xml layout, like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
<!-- some stuff -->
<myapp.widget.ClearableCaptionedButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:caption="to"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

can anybody spot something? thanks.

Comment: i edited my post and changed the name of the package to myapp.widget to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am confused by your two XML layouts.

The second one is where you say you use the widget. Hence, I am assuming that the class named `ClearableCaptionedButton` is in the package `de.pockettaxi.widget`.

I am further assuming that the `Button` and `ImageView` shown in your first layout are things that are always supposed to be in `ClearableCaptionButton`, not something supplied by the reuser of `ClearableCaptionButton`.

If those assumptions are all correct, then you have two problems.

- First, you aren't using the first
  layout anywhere that I can see.
- Second, the first
  layout has reference to a `myapp.widget.ClearableCaptionedButton` that probably does not exist.

I would replace the `myapp.widget.ClearableCaptionedButton` element with a `<merge>` element, then inflate that layout in the constructor or `onFinishInflate()` of `ClearableCaptionedButton`.

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Views/ColorMixer) from one of my books that shows the use of a custom widget that works in this manner.

Also, given your package name, I hope that it is either a very large pocket or a very small taxi... :-)

Comment: ok, i'm gonna try it that way.
i already thought about inflating the xml manually. thing is, i tried to do it the same way as in some android applications. if you have a look at the "KindSectionView" in DialtactsActivity provided in the android source, they (afaics) don't use an inflater but just an xml-layout with an element of the same name as the custom component.
actually, this worked fine for another component i made, but there, i only created it from source, not from xml.

Comment: @Julian Arz: Reputedly, there is some magic way to get it to auto-inflate, but I never got it to work, and it would not save that much code, anyway.

Comment: your sample project and along with this post helped me fix my layout also.  I had problems with the constructor until I followed your example