# Why is my variable null?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code:

```
public class Level extends Activity{

    public static String TAG="Level";

    Level_Score_bar score_bar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level_layout);

        score_bar=(Level_Score_bar) findViewById(R.id.Score_Bar);
        Log.d(TAG,"score_bar="+score_bar);
    }
}
```

The XML code looks like this (R.layout.level_layout) (Non-important stuff removed)

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar android:id="@+id/Score_Bar" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar>
</LinearLayout>
```

The log statement reads "score_bar=null".As you can see, there is a resource named R.id.Score_Bar.  Am I missing something? I need to use the function for some other stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things that can cause this.  The most common being that for one reason or another `R.id` was not generated correctly.  Usually doing a simple 'clean' will fix this.  If that doesn't work another thing to check would be the constructor for the custom view.  You can find this and other suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-com).

Comment: Was using super(Context), not Super(context,attrs)... Sigh. Thanks for the help!