# Add custom view as a view of XML layout

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

The scenario is the following:

I have an activity *RunTrainingWorkoutsView* that uses XML layout _run_workout.xml_ with some labels that are updated by *CountDownTimer*. Works fine...

Now, apart from labels that are updated every sec by *onTick()* callback method of CountDownTimer object I want to add a custom surface view to my _run_workout.xml layout_ that would draw some arcs updated by the same *onTick()* method every second...

my run_workout.xml:

```
<training.timer.CounterClockView 
    android:id="@+id/counter_clock_surface"
    android:layout_width="300dp" 
    android:layout_height="240dp">
</training.timer.CounterClockView>
```

My custom View extends *surfaceView*

```
public class CounterClockView extends SurfaceView {

Paint paint = new Paint();
Paint paint2 = new Paint();

final RectF rect = new RectF();
final RectF rect2 = new RectF();

int counterArcAngle = 15;
//constructor
public CounterClockView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context);

    //setting some paint properties...

    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    rect.set(50, 50, 150, 150);
    rect2.set(50, 50, 150, 150);

    this.layout(0, 0, 200, 200);

    canvas.drawArc(rect, -90, 360, false, paint);
    canvas.drawArc(rect2, -90, counterArcAngle, false, paint2);

}
```

My main class that extends activity is getting the reference to a custom *surfaceView* in the layout with the following code:

```
//counterClockView  is declared outside of onCreate() as CounterClockView counterClockView;  

//later in onCreate(){....
counterClockView  = (CounterClockView) findViewById(R.id.counter_clock_surface);
```

The problem is changing the value of member variables of customView object (counterClockView)

```
counterClockView.counterArcAngle = 10;
```

will crash the app...

Also, from my main activity I would like to call *invalidate()* method to redo the surface view after changing the *counterArcAngle* value, but this causes app to crash too...

Why can't create *counterClockView* object and reference it to a xml layout element of the same type and the change its appereance, invalidate it etc. ?

*EDIT LogCat*:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{training.timer/training.timer.RunTrainingWorkoutsView}: java.lang.NullPointerException

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at training.timer.RunTrainingWorkoutsView.onCreate(RunTrainingWorkoutsView.java:72)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: what's the error log? read the output from `LogCat`

Comment: `RunTrainingWorkoutsView.onCreate()` in this method, line 72 in this file `RunTrainingWorkoutsView.java`, one object is being `NULL`. Check it out!

Comment: Well, that is the question... If I had:TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(...) it wouldn't be NULL so the question is why is my custom view (surfaceView) NULL???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it after 3 days of banging my head against the wall and by googling, stacOverflowing etc.

Actually, it was this stupid little thing...

My XML file where I defined the layout containing some usual android views (textView and buttons namely) and my custom view *CounterClockView* I had:

```
<training.timer.CounterClockView 
android:id="@+id/counter_clock_surface"
android:layout_width="300dp" 
android:layout_height="240dp">
```

where I had to have added one more line!

```
<training.timer.CounterClockView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   !!!
    android:id="@+id/counter_clock_surface"
    android:layout_width="300dp" 
    android:layout_height="240dp">
</training.timer.CounterClockView>
```

I have no idea why this namespace line made such a huge difference, but it works great!

Now, I can update my custom view from my main activity on every *onTick()* of *CountDownTimer()*...

The following answer was very helpful:
[findViewById() returns null for custom component in layout XML, not for other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-co)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, so I just implemented all the three constructors in the Java class of my custom view all the three constructors plus onDrow method and it worked like a charm. Try it.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomWorldWideView extends View {

    public CustomWorldWideView(Context context) {

        super(context);
    }

    public CustomWorldWideView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomWorldWideView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Some simple draw on the view...
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA800"));


        Path path = new Path();

        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(getWidth() / 2, 0);
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight()/2);
        path.lineTo(getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
        path.lineTo( 0, getHeight());
        path.lineTo( 0, 0);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);


    }
}
```

The XML :

```
        <PackageName.CustomWorldWideView
            android:layout_width="56.00dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:id="@+id/world_wide_grid_view_2"
            />
```