# Unfortunately,NavigationBar has stopped in android studio emulator

Tags: android

```
I have done all my coding in android studio but when I am running my app in android studio emulator it's not working.
    here is my code:-     
    **MainActivity.java**

        package com.example.arpi.navigationbar;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.app.ActionBar;


        public class MainActivity extends Activity
                implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

            /**
             * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
             */
            private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

            /**
             * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
             */
            private CharSequence mTitle;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
                mTitle = getTitle();

                // Set up the drawer.
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                        R.id.navigation_drawer,
                        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
                Fragment objFragment=null;

                switch (position){

                    case 0:
                        objFragment=new menu1_Fragment();

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        objFragment=new menu2_Fragment();

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        objFragment=new menu3_Fragment();
                        break;
                }
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                        .commit();
            }

            private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
                return null;
            };

            public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
                switch (number) {
                    case 1:
                        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                        break;
                }
            }

            public void restoreActionBar() {
                ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            private ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
                return null;
            }


            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
                    // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
                    // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
                    // decide what to show in the action bar.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    restoreActionBar();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            /**
             * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
             */
            public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
                /**
                 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
                 * fragment.
                 */
                private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

                /**
                 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
                 * number.
                 */
                public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
                    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    return fragment;
                }

                public PlaceholderFragment() {
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    return rootView;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
                    super.onAttach(activity);
                    ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                            getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
                }
            }

        }
I have made three menu for navigationbar.i am not able to see the output as the app is not able to run emulator.please provide the solution for my problem.
   These are the different menu for navigation bar:-

***menu1_Fragment.java***
    package com.example.arpi.navigationbar;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    /**
     * Created by user on 26-06-2015.
     */
    public class menu1_Fragment extends Fragment {
        View rootview;
        @Nullable
        @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
            rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout,container,false);
            return  rootview;

        }

    }


    ***NavigationDrawerFragment.java***

    package com.example.arpi.navigationbar;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    /**
     * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
     * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
     * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
     */
    public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {


        private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";


        private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

        private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;


        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerListView;
        private View mFragmentContainerView;

        private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
        private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
        private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

        public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
            // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
                mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
            }

            // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
            selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
            mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });
            mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[]{
                            getString(R.string.title_section1),
                            getString(R.string.title_section2),
                            getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    }));
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
            return mDrawerListView;
        }

        public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
            return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        /**
         * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
         *
         * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
         * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
         */
        public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
            mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
            mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

            // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
            // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
            // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                    mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    if (!isAdded()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    if (!isAdded()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                        // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                        // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                        mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                        sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                    }

                    getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
            };

            // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
            // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
            }

            // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
            mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                }
            });

            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        }

        private void selectItem(int position) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
            if (mDrawerListView != null) {
                mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
            if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
            }
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mCallbacks = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
            // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
            if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
                showGlobalContextActionBar();
            }
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
         * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
         */
        private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }

        private ActionBar getActionBar() {
            return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        }

        /**
         * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
         */
        public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
            /**
             * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
             */
            void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
        }
    }
```

This is the Logcat.There are some errors due to ehich ai am not able see the output.
    ***Logcat error:-***
    06-27 14:59:09.667    2791-2791/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    06-27 14:59:12.277    2791-2791/com.example.arpi.navigationbar E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    06-27 14:59:19.408    2791-2791/com.example.arpi.navigationbar D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    06-27 14:59:19.408    2791-2791/com.example.arpi.navigationbar W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    06-27 14:59:19.508    2791-2791/com.example.arpi.navigationbar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arpi.navigationbar/com.example.arpi.navigationbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
                at com.example.arpi.navigationbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.arpi.navigationbar.NavigationDrawerFragment that is not a Fragment
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
                at com.example.arpi.navigationbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
                at com.example.arpi.navigationbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Filter the Logcat output for the word 'exception' and see if that sheds any light on what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Check this line in logcat `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arpi.navigationbar/com.example.arpi.navigationbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity` this shows that android system is not able to parse your layout xml due to `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException`. 
**Check**
 
[error-inflating-class-fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424853/error-inflating-class-fragment)
[inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment)