# Error InflateException Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity

I get de Error when i try run my app. I tried to change the class to `extends Fragment` and `extends FragmentActivity` with the imports but did not work.
For I have added some additional information in my Manifest, I think you might have something that might be causing the problem reported.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!--Mostrar a localização atual-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAjLBXa8xptO-7CRhvhRQMX8zB-85uR7LU"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**logcat error**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 22:55:13.475 3005-3005/luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp  E/AndroidRuntime: Process: luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp, PID: 3005
11-17 22:55:13.475 3005-3005/luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp/luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp.Ma inActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML  file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-17 22:55:13.475 3005-3005/luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-17 22:55:13.475 3005-3005/luizugliano.com.br.googlemapsapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
```

**My content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static  com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW;
import static com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();


        double latitude = 0;
        double longitude = 0;
        GPSTracker gps;
        gps = new GPSTracker(this);
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){
            latitude=gps.getLatitude();
            longitude=gps.getLongitude();
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .title("Hello Maps ");
            marker.icon(
                    defaultMarker(HUE_YELLOW));
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(longitude,
                            latitude)).zoom(1).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }else{
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

/**function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you **/

GoogleMap googleMap;
private void initilizeMap() {

    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Showing / hiding your current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable my location button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your manifest file

Comment: Did you try this one?   http://stackoverflow.com/a/19952291/3118054

Comment: Yes, but didn't work! @VipulPatel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead of `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` as you are using the SupportLibraries AppCompatActivity.

I think you also should replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()` for the same reason.

Having the same classes in support library and in regular API sometimes is  a real pain in the ass, because you always have to make sure you are using the right one.

Comment: Apart from the changes you mentioned, I had to also change the `MapFragment` to `SupportMapFragment` but still returning the same error.  Changed code: `googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();`.

Comment: I suppose you are using android studio. Did you include the dependencies for `google-play-services` in your build.gradle?

Comment: yep - i include `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'`

Comment: I just noticed: You are setting your contentView to `R.layout.activity_main`, but your layout is named `content_main`. Is this correct or a typo?

Comment: it was just an error in the time to copy the code here. Correct really `content_main`. Can it be related to some setting in my `Manifest?` I'm trying to edit my question entering my `Manifest` but is not allowing to have a lot of code in question.