# I get strange errors

Tags: android

So as I'm trying to run my android application, it will not correctly start, even if the Build was successful.

This is what my android monitor says:

```
07-21 05:20:59.832 28253-28253/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000020/n/armeabi
07-21 05:20:59.870 28253-28253/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10298000
07-21 05:20:59.874 28253-28253/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11055438
07-21 05:21:00.160 28253-28402/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/agl: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
07-21 05:21:00.179 28253-28384/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
07-21 05:21:00.300 28253-28253/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-21 05:21:00.302 28253-28253/com.example.testingmapingmarker23 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.testingmapingmarker23, PID: 28253
                                                                                   Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:system, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testingmapingmarker23/com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                       at com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:50)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                       at com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:50) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #9: Duplicate id 0x7f0d007d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3447)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                       at com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:50) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 


at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616
```

Sadly I have absolutely no clue what these errors mean.

Can someone help me?

Maybe it helps: I'm working on a Toolbar.

My activity_maps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        tools:context="com.example.testingmapingmarker23.MapsActivity"
        />




   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"

        android:title="Hello"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TEDO"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the values.xml (first dozen of lines - else there are too many characters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="design_fab_shadow_end_color">@android:color/transparent</color>
    <color name="design_fab_shadow_mid_color">#14000000</color>
    <color name="design_fab_shadow_start_color">#44000000</color>
    <color name="design_fab_stroke_end_inner_color">#0A000000</color>
    <color name="design_fab_stroke_end_outer_color">#0F000000</color>
    <color name="design_fab_stroke_top_inner_color">#1AFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="design_fab_stroke_top_outer_color">#2EFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="design_snackbar_background_color">#323232</color>
    <color name="design_textinput_error_color_dark">#FFFF6E6E</color>
    <color name="design_textinput_error_color_light">#FFD50000</color>
    <declare-styleable name="AppBarLayout"><attr name="elevation"/><attr name="android:background"/><attr format="boolean" name="expanded"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="AppBarLayoutStates"><attr format="boolean" name="state_collapsed"/><attr format="boolean" name="state_collapsible"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="AppBarLayout_Layout"><attr name="layout_scrollFlags">
```

Comment: What is on line #9 in your layout file `Binary XML file line #9`

Comment: Is my styles.xml the binary xml file or where can I find this?

Comment: Post your layout xml file

Comment: Hope this is the correct one

Comment: maybe this guys solution might be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19952291/1545085

Comment: @MrHarrison kindly check my answer .Let me inform

Answer (score 0):

**Don't**

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

**Do**

```
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

After that **`CLEAN-REBUILD`** & **`RUN`** .