# getting error in OS version 4.4

Tags: android, inflate-exception

my app is working fine in android version 5.0 and app but in 4.4 im getting error.

here is the error

```
04-18 18:10:50.575 19764-19764/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.administrator.mosbeau, PID: 19764
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.administrator.mosbeau/com.example.administrator.mosbeau.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
```

i use navigation drawer

here is my activity_main.xml

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.administrator.mosbeau.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the error is in this part of my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

anyone can help me to fix this error.

thanks

Comment: Working fine for me , is your  android:name in <fragment > tag correct ?

Comment: yes the android:name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment) quite similar to this. It has been solved by lot of 
people in different ways , so I guess there is no one way to solve this.

I have triaged many solutions , some things which you can check is :

1. `NavigationDrawerFragment` extending `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`;
2. Your `Android Manifest` has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`
3. If using actionBar activity , check its import :

Instead of this :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

Use this :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

4. Check build.gradle :

   `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`
    `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`

There are other ways too , do checkout answers in that post.

Comment: still not working.. the error is in this part of the code.. protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Is your NavigationDrawerFragment extending import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;