# Inflation Exceptions when developping Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing cordova plugins for android based on android libraries and components. In many of my adaptations I encountered the `Inflation exception` error in many of them.

I created many issues regarding this here is my last one : 
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues/524

These exceptions don't come out when I use the library inside a native android studio app. 
Here I am asking about the potential reasons for this kind of error to emerge from a Cordova plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment)

Comment: the issue on Github lacks the reference to the layout which is being inflated there. it's certainly one of them https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/tree/master/library/src/main/res/layout (but no clue which one it is).

Comment: @MartinZeitler The problem is that this is not my edited Layout. This is the one coming with a library, that when used with an android studio project does work fine. and I am using the same API and SDK and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could `git clone https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker.git`

and then add that project as a dependency, with fixed layout `mdtp_daypicker_group.xml` -

or even fork it, fix the layout/styles and then create a pull request (to have it fixed in their repository).

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

most likely should be:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

but then it complains:

> ?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless requires API level 21 (current min is 14)

you'd either have add this style `res/values-v16/styles.xml` and possibly up until API level `19` (or even up until `28`, in one does not want to use those resources) - 
or set the `minSdkLevel` to `21`.

adding `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` into `res/values/styles.xml` should also make the layout work (without the `android:` prefix), because this would declare the style for all API levels ...while not using any Android SDK resources.

Comment: So it is not a problem with Cordova ? just a problem with the library itself ? Why does it only happen when used in a Cordova plugin ?

Comment: It worked, I'll ask the repo to change it or I'll do the pull myself. thanks