# I cannot seem to run my android studio project on an older android phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-api-levels

I'm working on a game project for one of my college coding classes (written in java), and I'm using Android studio.  I understand java basics, though I'm new to Android studio.  My main issue has to do with running/testing my project on older API/SDK versions, specifically on an older phone.

I've been developing on Android 8.0 (Oreo) on API 26, though I also have Pie installed (API 28).  Currently, my targetSDKVersion is 26, compileSDKVersion is 26, and my minSDKVersion is 19.

I'm trying to run my app (called AMaze) on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (API 19), and that's why my minSDKVersion is 19.  It runs completely fine on phones that support Android 8.0 and above, as far as I'm aware.  But when I run the app on my Galaxy S4, it opens and crashes instantly saying "Unfortunately, your *application* has stopped".  I cannot figure out how to solve this.

I've scoured StackOverflow and the Android Developers website for answers, but with minimal luck.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project using the gradle, I've tried disabling Instant Run, and I've tried to make the compileSDKVersion 19 instead of 26 (but that causes the compiler to get angry, saying that Google Play requires it to be 26 or above).  My phone I'm assuming is android compatible (see https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility), and I followed the instructions to connect the phone to my computer (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app).  Based on the Developers website, it SEEMS all I should have to do is set minSDKVersion to the correct level, and adjust for any API deprecation and updates in the code (which I think I've done).  But it still doesn't work.

What I did discover is that my code is producing an inflate exception in the onCreate() method of my main activity (called AMazeActivity).  Seems like a variety of things can cause this error, but I cannot figure out my root cause.  This guy has a similar situation: 
[android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment/19952291)

Here is the entire error message I get after running the app on the phone.  The error message says my inflate exception is due to trying to inflate Spinner :

```
12/27 22:08:17: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Users\jandj\AndroidStudioProjects\AMaze\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop cs.cs301.amaze
$ adb shell am start -n "cs.cs301.amaze/cs.cs301.amaze.gui.AMazeActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 28224 on device samsung-sgh_m919-47dccee4
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16265: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16267: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16269: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16273: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 708: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 730: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 485: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 491: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 492: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 495: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 496: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 503: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 516: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 531: Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16736: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageButton.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageIcon
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16759: Landroid/widget/ImageButton;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 671: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 673: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 194 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17062: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17063: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17064: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17065: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17066: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17109: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17110: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17111: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17064: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0163
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.obtain, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.createStaticLayoutForMeasuring
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15540: Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;.obtain (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/text/TextPaint;I)Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
D/ProgressBar: setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 36
D/AbsSeekBar: AbsSeekBar Constructor: mAllowedSeeBarAnimation = true
D/ProgressBar: setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 36
    setProgressDrawable getHeight() = 0
    updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
    updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
    updateDrawableBounds: right = -96
    updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 0
    updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Spinner.getPopupContext, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.getPopupContext
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17017: Landroid/widget/Spinner;.getPopupContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000d
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x7f050026 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
E/AMazeActivity: onCreate
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at cs.cs301.amaze.gui.AMazeActivity.onCreate(AMazeActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:215)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:1626)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:629)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.<init>(AbsSpinner.java:74)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:174)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:153)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:166)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:132)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at cs.cs301.amaze.gui.AMazeActivity.onCreate(AMazeActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417eeda0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: cs.cs301.amaze, PID: 28224
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cs.cs301.amaze/cs.cs301.amaze.gui.AMazeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at cs.cs301.amaze.gui.AMazeActivity.onCreate(AMazeActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:215)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:1626)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:629)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.<init>(AbsSpinner.java:74)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:174)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:153)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:166)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:132)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at cs.cs301.amaze.gui.AMazeActivity.onCreate(AMazeActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28224 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Here is where the crash happens in my main activity.  I try to surround the code in a try/catch block to catch the exception and print it out more cleanly, which is shone above:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_amaze);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.getCause();
            Log.e("AMazeActivity", "onCreate", e);
            throw e;
        }
.  .  .
.  .  .
```

Things to note: I'm using a Constraints layout for my activities, I'm only using one custom view in the program, and I'm using no custom themes.  Here's the XML file where the exception complains about Spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="cs.cs301.amaze.gui.AMazeActivity">

   .  .  .

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diff_JFrame"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="256dp"
        android:text="Difficulty/Size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   .  .  .

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mazeGen"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        android:entries="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
   .  .  .
```

I think it's likely just a matter of changing a few lines in the settings (maybe in gradle, the manifest file, R class, an XML file, etc), but I don't know what to change or where.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
android:entries="@color/colorAccent"
```

to

```
android:entries="@array/yourarrayname"
```