# Error inflating class android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView, can someone tell me what I'm missing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-places-api

I'm working on getting the Google Place API to appear within a CardView.

The particular code I'm looking at is from GitHub, seems to be working for everyone else but I don't understand why it's throwing me an error.

This is the error I am getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury, PID: 6818
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury/com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury.CustomerMapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50 in com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury:layout/activity_customer_maps: Binary XML file line #50 in com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury:layout/activity_customer_maps: Error inflating class android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50 in com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury:layout/activity_customer_maps: Binary XML file line #50 in com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury:layout/activity_customer_maps: Error inflating class android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50 in com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury:layout/activity_customer_maps: Error inflating class android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:438)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3324)
        at com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury.CustomerMapsActivity.onCreate(CustomerMapsActivity.java:116)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury-Nkg-1mQCfbE8I1MoJKHQuA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury-Nkg-1mQCfbE8I1MoJKHQuA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 32 more
```

The main takeaway is that there is an Error inflating class android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView and that the issue is at line 50 of the XML.

This is the XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomerLogin" >


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttons">
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:text="logout"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/history"
                android:text="history"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:text="Settings"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20sp">



//***LINE 50 WHERE THE ERROR IS***



            <android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:ignore="ExtraText">
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            </android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/driverInfo"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="40sp">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So I guess there is something wrong with the FragmentContainerView? But i'm not getting any errors in the code and nothing is coming up on Google.

I feel like maybe something is outdated rather than outright incorrect but I haven't a clue.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Does this answer your question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment

Comment: try change your android:name to class refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19952291/7806581

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` – You have a typo in that layout tag. You're missing the `x` in `androidx`: `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`. You have it correct in the first tag.

Comment: @riizwaan were you able to resolve this? getting the same error any insights would be helpful

Comment: Did you find an answer for that error? I have the same problem which you had

Answer (score 40):

just try to define your startDestination in your navigation xml !

Comment: Thanks,
 In my case I set different path for  reference

Comment: This should be the correct answer, for me the `startDestination` id is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. What a cryptic error message. If I didn't find your answer, I wouldn't have a clue it's related to nav component.

Comment: I had a typo in my `startDestination`. After correcting

Comment: I changed the packages for fragments but didn't notice that they didn't changed in navigation.xml file

Answer (score 9):

You should implement new `androidx.fragment` dependencies to use `FragmentContainerView`. It is already added since version 1.2.0. You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5"
```

Comment: For Kotlin: `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'`.

Comment: Why does this work?  You'd think Fragments are very much a part of the standard Android libs.

Comment: @SMBiggs no, Android is moving to a model where SDK classes are provided in (static) libraries, not by the platform they run on. So there's an `android.app.Fragment` that's deprecated, and an `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` that you should use in its place.

Answer (score 9):

This problem was created for me as well. The reason was two mistakes.

1.I did not add startDestination in nav graph .

2.I did not add @AndroidEntryPoint annotation  in MainActivitey .

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had a Model which was used as arguments but I had not implemented Serializable and Parcelable implementaion.

Answer (score 6):

This error will only occur after you have added ProGuard & R8 to your project. To fix it, add the following two lines in `proguard-rule.pro`:

```
-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{}
```

Comment: This error comes on release so this is working one

Answer (score 5):

For me it was a typo within one of the fragments the `navGraph`, in the class path of the `android:name` attribute.. Adding a wrong path for the fragment class doesn't provide a compile time error, instead it raises `android.view.InflateException...Error inflating class android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`

So, make sure to have a correct packaging path for your fragments in `android:name`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android....MainFragment"  // <<<< This must be a correct path 
        android:label="main_fragment"
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is Due to Proguard Then add few lines

In proguard-rules.pro file

```
....
# for FragmentContainerView error
-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I looked deeper inside my stacktrace and found this line: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentContainerView must have an android:id to add Fragment MyFragment`. Giving it an id and specifying `tools:layout` fixed problem

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error was related to Serializable and Parcelable. To fix it, add the following two lines in proguard-rule.pro:

```
-keepnames class * extends android.os.Parcelable
-keepnames class * extends java.io.Serializable
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, despite the same error, reason was different.
However this info about adding some rules to proguard-rules.pro pointed me into the right direction. This, and some other clues in error log about problems with argument in navigation XML file.
Eventually I found that it was problem with using my own classes in argument. And I don't mean the class of argument, but the fact that this class also used  some of my other classes. And it was enough to add rules for each of these other classes:

```
-keepnames class <MyClass>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity must be a child of FragmentActivity to use androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView either you extend the FragmentActivity or the AppCompatActivity which is a child FragmentActivity class. It is recommended to extend the AppCompatActivity.

see: https://www.tutorialguruji.com/android/trying-to-use-navhostfragment-and-im-getting-an-error-error-inflating-class-androidx-fragment-app-fragmentcontainerview/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30160133)

Answer (score 1):

1. First add `fragment` dependency- [latest version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#declaring_dependencies)

`implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.7"`

2. If you getting error in `xml`. Click on that and scroll down click on **"Do not warn"** your view will be **visible**.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
if still this issue not resolved.

Please check if you your activity extending FragmentActivity or not.

suppose your activity is CustomerMapsActivity.

Need to check if CustomerMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity or not.
if CustomerMapsActivity extends BaseActivity, check BaseActivity should extends FragmentActivity.

To inflate this "android.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView" we need FragmentActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably after **Refactor->Remove unused resources** you can lost **id** from your `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` - bring it back

Answer (score 0):

If you have done all the solutions and still the problem stands maybe you should check if your `fragment constructor` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was absence of **@AndroidEntryPoint** in an Activity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).