# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml

I published my application to the Play Store as open beta. I don't get any error when I run it with the emulator or by connecting the phone through Android Studio. However, when I install the application as apk on the phone, it throws it from the application and I get the following error on the Play Console.

**Error:**

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook/com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.ui.create_edit_view_password.CreateEditViewPasswordActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook:layout/activity_create_edit_view_password: Binary XML file line #21 in com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook:layout/activity_create_edit_view_password: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3635)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3792)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate (Interrogator.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil (UiControllerImpl.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil (UiControllerImpl.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent (UiControllerImpl.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp (MotionEvents.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp (MotionEvents.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap (Tap.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.-$$Nest$smsendSingleTap
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap (Tap.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform (GeneralClickAction.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform (ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform (ViewInteraction.java:23)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call (ViewInteraction.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call (ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook:layout/activity_create_edit_view_password: Binary XML file line #21 in com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook:layout/activity_create_edit_view_password: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook:layout/activity_create_edit_view_password: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook:navigation/nav_graph_password_create_edit_view line 20
at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate (NavInflater.java)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue (SynchronizedLazyImpl.java)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.getNavHostController$navigation_fragment_release (NavHostFragment.java)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate (NavHostFragment.java)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create (FragmentStateManager.java)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:10)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.\<init\> (FragmentContainerView.java:10)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView (FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView (FragmentController.java:4)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:4)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:4)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:1073)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:1001)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:538)
at com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.ui.create_edit_view_password.CreateEditViewPasswordActivity.onCreate (CreateEditViewPasswordActivity.java)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8050)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8030)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1329)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3608)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3792)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate (Interrogator.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil (UiControllerImpl.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil (UiControllerImpl.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent (UiControllerImpl.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp (MotionEvents.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp (MotionEvents.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap (Tap.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.-$$Nest$smsendSingleTap
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap (Tap.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform (GeneralClickAction.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform (ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform (ViewInteraction.java:23)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call (ViewInteraction.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call (ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.database.entities.Entry
at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflateArgument (NavInflater.java)
at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate (NavInflater.java)
at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate (NavInflater.java)
at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate (NavInflater.java)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.database.entities.Entry
at java.lang.Class.classForName
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:454)
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:379)
at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflateArgument (NavInflater.java)
```

**nav_graph.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_password_create_view_edit"
    app:startDestination="@id/createPasswordFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/createPasswordFragment"
        android:name="com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.ui.create_edit_view_password.fragments.CreatePasswordFragment"
        android:label="fragment_create_password"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_password" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/viewPasswordsFragment"
        android:name="com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.ui.create_edit_view_password.fragments.ViewPasswordsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_view_passwords"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_view_passwords">
        <argument
            android:name="data"
            app:argType="com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.database.entities.Entry" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/editPasswordFragment"
        android:name="com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.ui.create_edit_view_password.fragments.EditPasswordFragment"
        android:label="fragment_edit_password"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_password">
        <argument
            android:name="data"
            app:argType="com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.database.entities.Entry" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".ui.create_edit_view_password.CreateEditViewPasswordActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/createEditViewPassword_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_password_create_edit_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment.kt:**

```
class CreatePasswordFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentCreatePasswordBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var adapter: PasswordAccountInfoAdapter

    private val accountDetailList = mutableListOf<EntryDetail>()
    private lateinit var viewModel: CreateEditViewPasswordViewModel

    private fun rand(from: Int, to: Int): Int {
        val random = Random()
        return random.nextInt(to - from) + from
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentCreatePasswordBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        val mBottomSheetDialog = RoundedBottomSheetDialog(requireContext())
        val sheetView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_options, null)
        mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView)
        val sheetBinding: BottomSheetOptionsBinding = BottomSheetOptionsBinding.bind(sheetView)

        val rvAccountDetails = binding.createPasswordAccountDetailsRecyclerView
        adapter = PasswordAccountInfoAdapter(accountDetailList)
        rvAccountDetails.adapter = adapter
        rvAccountDetails.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,
            0
        ) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            ): Boolean {
                val startPos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val endPos = target.adapterPosition
                Collections.swap(accountDetailList, startPos, endPos)
                adapter.notifyItemMoved(startPos, endPos)
                return true
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}
        })

        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.createPasswordAccountDetailsRecyclerView)

        val num = rand(1, 4)

        if (num == 1 || num == 2) {
            FancyShowCaseView.Builder(requireActivity())
                .focusOn(binding.createPasswordNewEntryImageView)
                .title(getString(R.string.add_new_item_text))
                .build()
                .show()
        } else {
            FancyShowCaseView.Builder(requireActivity())
                .focusOn(binding.createPasswordIconImageView)
                .title(getString(R.string.select_icon_text))
                .build()
                .show()
        }

        var companyIcon = 0

        binding.createPasswordBackButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), PasswordActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            (activity as CreateEditViewPasswordActivity).finish()
            (activity as CreateEditViewPasswordActivity).overridePendingTransition(
                R.anim.slide_in_left,
                R.anim.slide_out_right
            )
        }

        viewModel = (activity as CreateEditViewPasswordActivity).viewModel

        binding.createPasswordIconImageView.setOnClickListener {

            val iBottomSheetDialog = RoundedBottomSheetDialog(requireContext())
            val sheetView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.company_chooser_sheet, null)
            iBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView)
            val companySheetBinding: CompanyChooserSheetBinding = CompanyChooserSheetBinding.bind(
                sheetView
            )
            val companyList = CompanyListData.companyListData
            val companyAdapter = LogoCompanyChooserAdapter(companyList)
            companySheetBinding.rvCompanyChooser.adapter = companyAdapter
            companySheetBinding.rvCompanyChooser.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            companySheetBinding.rvCompanyChooser.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
            iBottomSheetDialog.show()
            companyAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
                companyIcon = it.id
                Snackbar.make(
                    view,
                    "${it.companyName} " + getString(R.string.logo_selected_text),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                )
                    .show()
                iBottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
            }

            iBottomSheetDialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

            companySheetBinding.searchBar.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

                override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                    val companyListData = CompanyListData.companyListData
                    val filteredList = mutableListOf<CompanyList>()

                    if (p0 != null) {
                        for (company in companyListData) {
                            if (company.companyName.contains(p0)) {
                                filteredList.add(company)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    val filteredCompanyAdapter = LogoCompanyChooserAdapter(filteredList)
                    companySheetBinding.rvCompanyChooser.adapter = filteredCompanyAdapter

                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {}
            })

        }

        binding.createPasswordNewEntryImageView.setOnClickListener {
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(requireContext(), it)
            popupMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.account_details_menu, popupMenu.menu)
            popupMenu.show()

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
                when (menuItem.itemId) {
                    R.id.accountDetail_username -> {
                        showBottomSheet(mBottomSheetDialog, sheetBinding, 0)
                        popupMenu.dismiss()
                    }

                    R.id.accountDetail_email -> {
                        showBottomSheet(mBottomSheetDialog, sheetBinding, 1)
                        popupMenu.dismiss()
                    }

                    R.id.accountDetail_phone -> {
                        showBottomSheet(mBottomSheetDialog, sheetBinding, 2)
                        popupMenu.dismiss()
                    }

                    R.id.accountDetail_password -> {
                        showBottomSheet(mBottomSheetDialog, sheetBinding, 3)
                        popupMenu.dismiss()
                    }

                    R.id.accountDetail_website -> {
                        showBottomSheet(mBottomSheetDialog, sheetBinding, 4)
                        popupMenu.dismiss()
                    }

                    R.id.accountDetail_note -> {
                        showBottomSheet(mBottomSheetDialog, sheetBinding, 5)
                        popupMenu.dismiss()
                    }

                }
                true
            }

        }

        binding.createPasswordSaveImageView.setOnClickListener {

            val entryTitle = binding.createPasswordEntryTitleEditText.editText?.text.toString()

            val entryCategory: String =
                (binding.createPasswordCategoryChipGroup.children.toList().filter {
                    (it as Chip).isChecked
                }[0] as Chip).text.toString()

            val entryIcon = companyIcon

            val entryDetailsList = accountDetailList

            if (entryTitle.isNotEmpty() || entryTitle.isNotBlank()) {
                if (entryCategory.isNotEmpty() || entryCategory.isNotBlank()) {
                    if (entryDetailsList.isNotEmpty()) {

                        val dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                            requireContext(),
                            getString(R.string.saving_text),
                            getString(R.string.saving_description_text),
                            true,
                            false
                        )
                        dialog.show()

                        val password1 = PASSWORD1

                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

                            val entry = Entry(0, entryTitle, entryCategory, entryIcon, 0)

                            val id = async { viewModel.upsertEntry(entry) }.await()

                            for (entryDetail in entryDetailsList) {
                                val securityClass = EncryptionDecryption()
                                val encryptedObject = securityClass.encrypt(
                                    entryDetail.detailContent,
                                    password1,
                                    securityClass.getKey()
                                )
                                val encryptedData = encryptedObject.encryptedData
                                val emdKey = encryptedObject.key

                                entryDetail.id = 0
                                entryDetail.entryId = id
                                entryDetail.detailContent = encryptedData

                                val entryDetailId = async {
                                    viewModel.upsertEntryDetail(
                                        entryDetail
                                    )
                                }.await()
                                val saltObject = EncryptedKey(0, entryDetailId, emdKey)
                                async { viewModel.upsertEncryptedKey(saltObject) }.await()
                            }

                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                val intent = Intent(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    PasswordActivity::class.java
                                )
                                startActivity(intent)
                                (activity as CreateEditViewPasswordActivity).finish()
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(
                            view,
                            getString(R.string.account_detail_error_text),
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        view,
                        getString(R.string.select_category_text),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(
                    view,
                    getString(R.string.title_cannot_blank_text),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }

        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun showBottomSheet(
        mBottomSheetDialog: RoundedBottomSheetDialog,
        sheetBinding: BottomSheetOptionsBinding,
        optionType: Int,
    ) {

        var detailType = ""

        sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.text?.clear()
        sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.clearFocus()

        when (optionType) {
            0 -> {
                detailType = "Username"
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.helperText =
                    getString(R.string.eg_text) + getString(R.string.username_text)
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL
            }

            1 -> {
                detailType = "Email"
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = false
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.helperText =
                    getString(R.string.eg_text) + getString(R.string.sample_email_text)
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL

            }

            2 -> {
                detailType = "Phone Number"
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = false
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED or InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.helperText =
                    getString(R.string.eg_text) + getString(R.string.sample_phone_number_text)
            }

            3 -> {
                detailType = "Password"
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = true
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.helperText =
                    getString(R.string.strong_password_text)
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
            }

            4 -> {
                detailType = "Website"
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = false
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.helperText =
                    getString(R.string.eg_text) + getString(R.string.sample_website_text)
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL
            }

            5 -> {
                detailType = "Notes"
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = false
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.minLines = 3
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.helperText =
                    getString(R.string.some_notes_text)
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
            }
        }

        sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.hint = detailType

        mBottomSheetDialog.show()

        sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsAddOptionButton.setOnClickListener {
            val validateMessage = validateInput(
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.text.toString(),
                optionType
            )
            if (validateMessage == getString(R.string.validated_text)) {
                val accountDetailObj = EntryDetail(
                    1,
                    1,
                    detailType,
                    sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.editText?.text.toString()
                )
                accountDetailList.add(accountDetailObj)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
            } else {
                sheetBinding.bottomSheetOptionsEditText.error = validateMessage
            }
        }

    }

    private fun validateInput(input: String, type: Int): String {...}

    private fun nullCheckInput(input: String): Boolean {
        return input.isNotEmpty() && input.isNotBlank()
    }
}
```

**entry.kt:**

```
package com.mahmutalperenunal.passwordbook.database.entities

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.io.Serializable

@Entity(tableName = "entry")
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val category: String,
    val icon: Int,
    var favourite: Int
) : Serializable
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998629