# Aplication crashing with Floating Button and Navigation Drawer Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

I have problem with my app. I make a floating button with animation from YT tutorial.  When I added this buttons my application can't start and crash.I made these buttons in content_main.xml and from this I am using binding. When I did this in another projekt without drawer everythig was working properly. Anyone know what is wrong?

```
package com.example.carplanner

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.View
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import com.example.carplanner.databinding.ContentMainBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    private lateinit var binding: ContentMainBinding


    private val rotateOpen: Animation by lazy {
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            this,
            R.anim.rotate_open_anim
        )
    }
    private val rotateClose: Animation by lazy {
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            this,
            R.anim.rotate_close_anim
        )
    }
    private val fromBottom: Animation by lazy {
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            this,
            R.anim.from_bottom_anim
        )
    }
    private val toBottom: Animation by lazy {
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            this,
            R.anim.to_bottom_anim
        )
    }

    private var clicked = false


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState,persistentState)

return  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    }

    private fun onAddButtonClicked() {
        setVisibility(clicked)
        setAnimation(clicked)
        setClickable(clicked)
        clicked = !clicked
    }

    private fun setVisibility(clicked: Boolean) {
        if (!clicked){
            binding.fuelBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.repairBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.ptBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.expensensBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.ocBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            binding.fuelBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            binding.repairBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            binding.ptBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            binding.expensensBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            binding.ocBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }


    private fun setAnimation(clicked: Boolean) {
        if (!clicked)
        {
            binding.fuelBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom)
            binding.repairBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom)
            binding.expensensBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom)
            binding.ocBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom)
            binding.ptBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom)

            binding.addBtn.startAnimation(rotateOpen)
        }else{
            binding.fuelBtn.startAnimation(toBottom)
            binding.repairBtn.startAnimation(toBottom)

            binding.expensensBtn.startAnimation(toBottom)
            binding.ocBtn.startAnimation(toBottom)
            binding.ptBtn.startAnimation(toBottom)

            binding.addBtn.startAnimation(rotateClose)
        }
    }
    private fun  setClickable(clicked: Boolean) {
        if (!clicked) {

            binding.fuelBtn.isClickable = true
            binding.ptBtn.isClickable = true
            binding.ocBtn.isClickable = true
            binding.expensensBtn.isClickable = true
            binding.repairBtn.isClickable = true


        } else {
            binding.fuelBtn.isClickable = false
            binding.ptBtn.isClickable = false
            binding.ocBtn.isClickable = false
            binding.expensensBtn.isClickable = false
            binding.repairBtn.isClickable = false
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        binding = ContentMainBinding.inflate((layoutInflater))
        setContentView(binding.root)


        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            onAddButtonClicked()
        }
        binding.fuelBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dodaj tankowanie", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        binding.repairBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dodaj naprawę", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        binding.expensensBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dodaj wydatki", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        binding.ocBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dodaj Ubezpieczenie", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        binding.ptBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dodaj przegląd techniczny", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(

            R.id.nav_home,
            R.id.nav_paliwo,
            R.id.nav_naprawa,
            R.id.nav_wydatki,
            R.id.nav_oc,
            R.id.nav_pt), drawerLayout)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController!!, appBarConfiguration!!)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController!!)
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration!!) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)


            return true

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.btn_settings) {
            val intent = Intent(
                    this, SettingsActivity ::class.java)
            startActivity (intent)
        }else{
            if (id == R.id.btn_about){
                val intent = Intent(
                    this, About ::class.java)
                startActivity (intent)
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:rippleColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fuel_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#1565C0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_btn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_paliwo" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/repair_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#1565C0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fuel_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fuel_btn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_naprawa"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/expensens_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#1565C0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/repair_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/repair_btn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wydatki" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/oc_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#1565C0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/expensens_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/expensens_btn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_oc" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/pt_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#1565C0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/oc_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/oc_btn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pt" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the errors:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.carplanner:layout/content_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.carplanner:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.carplanner:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.getContext()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:97)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.example.carplanner.databinding.ContentMainBinding.inflate(ContentMainBinding.java:66)
        at com.example.carplanner.databinding.ContentMainBinding.inflate(ContentMainBinding.java:60)
        at com.example.carplanner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-01-16 22:40:07.525 26936-26936/com.example.carplanner E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-01-16 22:40:07.582 26936-26936/com.example.carplanner I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26936 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Why did you place an `inflate` call before the call to `super.onCreate`? And what's with the multiple `setContentView` calls? The last two of them even seem to be referring to the same layout.

Comment: I did because it was on tutorial. About this to setContentView a tried something to connect with my layout. A made a udpate of code beacsue when I created new ```override fun onCreate``` it is opening but now clicking ```addBtn``` don't make any action.

Comment: There's no point in doing `setContentView(R.layout.content_main)` since you already have `setContentView(binding.root)`

Comment: I deleted this setContentView like you said, and make setOnClickListener in one ```override fun onCreate```. I mantion that separately button and actiobar is working. But together in on function app can't turn on.

Comment: @Michael I change this, but I don't know how to make these two thing together in on ```override fun onCreate```

Comment: @PatrykKwiatkowski check out [this answer at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19952291/9701793)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me. I don't know how to implement in ```onCreate``` My floatingbuttons  from ```ContentMain.xml``` and navigationdrawer from another layout