# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is the full *Logcat* output:

```
02/18 12:33:45: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 399 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.vector.preetest/com.vector.preetest.ui.main.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 10800 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/vector.preetes: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/vector.preetes: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/vector.preetes: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.vector.preetest
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/vector.preetes: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/vector.preetes: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vector.preetest, PID: 10800
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vector.preetest/com.vector.preetest.ui.main.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.vector.preetest:layout/main_activity: Binary XML file line #10 in com.vector.preetest:layout/main_activity: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.vector.preetest:layout/main_activity: Binary XML file line #10 in com.vector.preetest:layout/main_activity: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.vector.preetest:layout/main_activity: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.vector.preetest.ui.settings.ApiSettingsFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:566)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1059)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:639)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:592)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:557)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:539)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:166)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.vector.preetest.ui.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:548)
            ... 52 more
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
        at com.vector.preetest.ui.settings.ApiSettingsFragment.<init>(ApiSettingsFragment.kt:19)
            ... 55 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10800 SIG: 9
```

i have tried renaming the fragmentview in the activty to `class =`  instead of `android:name` as referred to in [question 19874882](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment) as well as make sure `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` is in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

This is the `Fragment`'s layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" >
    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT: `ApiSettingsFragment`, as requested

```
package com.vector.preetest.ui.settings

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.TableLayout
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.vector.preetest.R
import com.vector.preetest.databinding.FragmentApiSettingsBinding
import com.vector.preetest.repository.settings.ApiSettings
import com.vector.preetest.repository.settings.ApiSettingsRepository
import timber.log.Timber


class ApiSettingsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var user = viewModel.userId
    private var pwd = viewModel.password
    private var role = viewModel.userRole
    private var server = viewModel.serverUrl

  private lateinit var settingsBinding: FragmentApiSettingsBinding

  private lateinit var viewModel: SettingsViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        Timber.d("Arrived in SettingsFragment")

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            requireActivity(),
            SettingsViewModelFactory(
                ApiSettingsRepository.getInstance(requireContext())
            )
        ).get(SettingsViewModel::class.java)


        settingsBinding = FragmentApiSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater).apply {
            this.viewModel = viewModel
        }

         settingsBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_api_settings, container, false)
    }

    private fun navigateToMainFragment() {
        val apiSettings = ApiSettings(
            apiUid = user.value!!,
            apiPwd = pwd.value!!,
            apiServer = server.value!!,
            apiRole = role.value!!,
            settingsVerified = true
        )
        val action = ApiSettingsFragmentDirections.actionApiSettingsFragmentToMainFragment(settings = apiSettings)
        Timber.d("Faked settings, going back to MainFragment")
        if (!apiSettings.settingsVerified) {
            setSnack("Settings Invalid! Test Settings")
        }
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
    fun setSnack(message : String){
        Snackbar.make(
            requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            message,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.option_menu_confirm_settings -> navigateToMainFragment()
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays here

```
class ApiSettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    private var user = viewModel.userId
    private var pwd = viewModel.password
    private var role = viewModel.userRole
    private var server = viewModel.serverUrl
```

where `viewModel` hasn't been initialised yet resulting in

```
UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
        at com.vector.preetest.ui.settings.ApiSettingsFragment.<init>(ApiSettingsFragment.kt:19)
```

So the solution is to declare the above variables as `private lateinit var` and initialise them after `viewModel` itself has been initialised.

```
class ApiSettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var user: UserType
    private lateinit var pwd: PswType
    private lateinit var role: RoleType
    private lateinit var server: ServerType

    ...

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        Timber.d("Arrived in SettingsFragment")

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            requireActivity(),
            SettingsViewModelFactory(
                ApiSettingsRepository.getInstance(requireContext())
            )
        ).get(SettingsViewModel::class.java)

        user = viewModel.userId
        pwd = viewModel.password
        role = viewModel.userRole
        server = viewModel.serverUrl
    {
```