# .view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.iammert.library.readablebottombar.Readable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using this [Readable BottomBar Navigation](https://github.com/iammert/ReadableBottomBar) in my main activity but app keep crashing on launching of my main activity

I find discussion here for same error [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment) but I don't understand what exactly my problem is

my main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.iammert.library.readablebottombar.ReadableBottomBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:rbb_tabs="@xml/tabs" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainActivity Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Logcat  -

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
> ComponentInfo{com.choudhary.vendorapp/com.choudhary.vendorapp.MainActivity}:
>
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating 
> class com.iammert.library.readablebottombar.ReadableBottomBar
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error 
> inflating class com.iammert.library.readablebottombar.ReadableBottomBar
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class 
> com.iammert.library.readablebottombar.ReadableBottomBar
>  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
> at com.choudhary.vendorapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
> ```

tabs.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
    <tab text="@string/Home" />
    <tab text="@string/Order" />
    <tab text="@string/PayIn" />
    <tab text="@string/Profile" />
</tabs>
```

Comment: Did you follow the setup? (Did you add the dependency of the navigation bar to your dependencies in the build.gradle file?)

Comment: yes i added the dependencies

Comment: Interesting. Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragmen) SO post help?