# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.naman.tictactoe/com.naman.tictactoe.GameActivity}:

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner in android development I use kotlin (minimum API 21) to develop a tic tac toe game with a splash screen, Home Activity, game activity.

[img of all activity][1]

In which  after clicking Play button in home activity my app crash. The app crashes saying "Unfortunately app has stopped" when i run in the emulator. and shows the error AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in my logcat. Please help me to fix this error since i am new to kotlin and android

Please Help!

MainActivity.kt sorce code

```
package com.naman.tictactoe

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.WindowManager
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // This is used to hide the status bar and make
    // the splash screen as a full screen activity.

    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )
    // we used the postDelayed(Runnable, time) method
    // to send a message with a delayed time.
    Handler().postDelayed({
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }, 3000) // 3000 is the delayed time in milliseconds.
}}
```

HomeActivity.kt sorce code

```
package com.naman.tictactoe

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.View


class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)



    }

    fun play(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

GameActivity.kt sorcecode

```
package com.naman.tictactoe

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import com.naman.tictactoe.R.layout.activity_game


class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var buttons : Array<Array<ImageButton>>
private lateinit  var textViewPlayer1: TextView
private lateinit var textViewPlayer2: TextView

private var player1Turn: Boolean = true
private var roundCount: Int = 0
private var player1Point: Int = 0
private var player2Point: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(activity_game)

    textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.player1TextView)
    textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.player2TextView)


    buttons = Array(3){r->
        Array(3){c->
            initButtons(r,c)
        }
    }

    val btnReset: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.btnReset)
    btnReset.setOnClickListener{
        player1Point = 0
        player2Point = 0
        clearBoard()
        updateScore()
    }
}

private fun initButtons(r: Int, c: Int): ImageButton {
    val btn: ImageButton =
        findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("btn$r$c","id",packageName))
    btn.setOnClickListener{
        onButtonClick(btn)

    }
    return btn
}

private fun onButtonClick(btn: ImageButton) {
    if (btn.drawable != null) return
    if (player1Turn){
        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.couple_edt_cross)
    }else {
        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.couple_edt_heart)
    }
    roundCount++

    if (checkForWin()){
        if (player1Turn) win(1) else win(2)
    } else if(roundCount == 9){
        draw()
    }else{
        player1Turn = ! player1Turn
    }

}
private fun checkForWin(): Boolean {
    val field= Array(3){r->
        Array(3){c->
            getField(buttons[r][c])
        }
    }
    for (i in 0..2){
        if ((field[i][0] == field[i][1])&&
            (field[i][0] == field[i][2])&&
            (field[i][0] !=null)
        )return true


        if ((field[0][i] == field[1][i])&&
            (field[0][i] == field[2][i])&&
            (field[0][i] !=null)
        )return true


        if ((field[0][0] == field[1][1])&&
            (field[0][0] == field[2][2])&&
            (field[0][0] !=null )
        )return true


        if ((field[0][2] == field[1][1])&&
            (field[0][2] == field[2][0])&&
            (field[0][2] !=null )
        )return true

    }
    return false
}

private fun getField(btn: ImageButton): Char? {
    val drw: Drawable? = btn.drawable
    val drwCross: Drawable? = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.couple_edt_cross,null)
    val drwHeart: Drawable? = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.couple_edt_heart,null)

    return when(drw?.constantState){

        drwCross?.constantState -> 'X'
        drwHeart?.constantState -> 'O'
        else -> null
    }
}



private fun win(player: Int) {

    if (player == 1) player1Point++ else player2Point++
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Player $player Won!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    updateScore()
    clearBoard()

}

private fun clearBoard() {
    for (i in 0..2) for (j in 0..2) {
        buttons[i][j].setImageResource(0)
    }
    roundCount = 0
    player1Turn = true
}

private fun updateScore() {
    textViewPlayer1.text = "Player 1 : $player1Point"
    textViewPlayer2.text = "Player 2 : $player2Point"
}


private fun draw(){
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Match Draw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    clearBoard()
}


}
```

LogCat :

```
06-18 17:17:54.290 5994-5994/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)

06-18 17:17:54.339 5994-5994/? W/ActivityThread: Application com.naman.tictactoe is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...

06-18 17:17:54.358 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk

06-18 17:17:54.499 5994-5999/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Debugger is active

06-18 17:17:54.558 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: Debugger has connected

06-18 17:17:54.558 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-18 17:17:54.760 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-18 17:17:54.961 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-18 17:17:55.161 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-18 17:17:55.362 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-18 17:17:55.564 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-18 17:17:55.766 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-18 17:17:55.968 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/System.out: debugger has settled (1360)

06-18 17:17:55.972 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/com.naman.tictactoe-1/lib/x86

06-18 17:17:56.008 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe W/art: Before Android 4.1, method 
android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 
androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

06-18 17:18:08.308 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.308 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.316 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC 
freed 1766(187KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 11MB/14MB, paused 625us total 8.367ms

06-18 17:18:08.317 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.327 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC 
freed 379(22KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 618us total 10.127ms

06-18 17:18:08.327 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.339 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 85(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 634us total 11.276ms

06-18 17:18:08.339 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 394MB allocation

06-18 17:18:08.339 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.347 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1131(85KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(9MB) LOS objects, 43% free, 1357KB/2MB, paused 490us total 7.662ms

06-18 17:18:08.347 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to 
allocate a 414034332 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 382MB until OOM"

06-18 17:18:08.347 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.347 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.351 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.355 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.360 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 
394MB allocation

06-18 17:18:08.360 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc

06-18 17:18:08.365 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 
3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 43% free, 1357KB/2MB, paused 330us total 5.247ms

06-18 17:18:08.365 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 414034332 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 382MB until OOM"

06-18 17:18:08.365 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap

06-18 17:18:08.368 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash

06-18 17:18:08.368 5994-5994/com.naman.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.naman.tictactoe, PID: 5994
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.naman.tictactoe/com.naman.tictactoe.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.naman.tictactoe.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.kt:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.naman.tictactoe.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.kt:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.naman.tictactoe.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.kt:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 414034332 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 382MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.naman.tictactoe.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.kt:26) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
06-18 17:18:10.650 5994-5994/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5994 SIG: 9
'''


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQNSG.png
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment. Check this one out, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 414034332 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 382MB until OOM
> ```

There is a large bitmap referenced from `LinearLayout` at line 9 of the GameActivity layout, likely `android:background`. You can make the image smaller in terms of pixel resolution to reduce memory requirements.

Comment: I Thanks you a lot for Help. My App start working now I'm very happy now. Have a Nice Day

Answer (score -1):

In this log, we can see

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.naman.tictactoe/com.naman.tictactoe.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

So something wrong tag is added in the line no 9 in your GameActivity layout.