# There is no error show in coding but it will crash after I login to my home page. The logcat shows that the error is in the inflate line

Tags: java, android, firebase

There is no error show in coding but it will crash after I login to my home page. The logcat shows that the error is in the inflate line.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.jj.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.jj.R;
import com.example.jj.adapter.PostAdapter;
import com.example.jj.model.Post;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerViewPosts;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Post> postList;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        

        recyclerViewPosts = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_post);
        recyclerViewPosts.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerViewPosts.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postList);
        recyclerViewPosts.setAdapter(postAdapter);

        readPosts();

        return view;
    }

    private void readPosts() {

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);

                    postList.add(post);
                }

                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

and also my xml file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?android:attr/background">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="-20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/recycle_view_post"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How the error code looks like:

```
Process: com.example.jj, PID: 8988
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.jj:layout/fragment_home: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.jj:layout/fragment_home: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.jj:layout/fragment_home: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.example.jj.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:38)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10100d4 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:997)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:981)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5535)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:237)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:233)
```

Is there any solution for this as I have already check some similar question but looks like those solutions are not working for me...

Comment: why do you have 2 things with an ID of `android:id="@+id/bar"`

Comment: The problem is with the `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` element: `android:background="?android:attr/background"`. You very likely do not have an `android:background` defined in your theme, as that's not something you'd normally want to set there. Even if you do set that in the theme, that attribute on the `<Toolbar>` would be redundant, since that's what it would already be. Either remove that, or set it to an appropriate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this link
[android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment)

Your NestedScrollView and AppBarLayout have the same id.

```
android:id="@+id/bar"
```

Change the id and it may resolve the issues.

After reproducing the error, change the background color of the toolbar something like below:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">
         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="-20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info" />
        </RelativeLayout>
 </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I had changed my id but the problem still the same
Is there an error exist in my xml file?

Comment: Okay, I did try to reproduce your error and I found out that you have assigned the background color which is not available. Please, change the background color of the Toolbar. And, it will surely solve the issues. Set your background color something like below:

android:background="@color/white"

Comment: The inflate problem is solved but new problem pops out...
The error shows in this line:

recyclerViewPosts = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_post);

Comment: Because, there is no recycler view in your XML layout(fragment_home).

Comment: Thank you sir!! You just solved my problem!!
Thank a lot!!

Comment: Welcome, Can I get an upvote? If it solved your problem.

Comment: Sure sir. But I had not enough reputation for that but it already recorded