# Accessing Parent Activity Button in Fragment Crashes App

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

Hey guys I am a beginner in Android Develpoment. I am currently learning Navigation Components, but stuck in this app. I am setting listener to the button present in the activity_main.xml inside the FirstFragment.java and SecondFragment.java but my app crashes. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**Main Activity.java**

```
package com.ahstore.inventory;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.ahstore.inventory.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);




        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Inventory.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Inventory.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:scrollIndicators="none"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
package com.ahstore.inventory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.ahstore.inventory.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentFirstBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,container,false);


        return view;

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Button button1=view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

**fragment_first.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="First" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SecondFragment.java**

```
package com.ahstore.inventory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.ahstore.inventory.databinding.FragmentSecondBinding;

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSecondBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second,container,false);

        return view;

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button button=view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

**fragment_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="am second"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error**

```
2022-03-04 16:54:11.473 2392-2392/com.ahstore.inventory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ahstore.inventory, PID: 2392
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ahstore.inventory/com.ahstore.inventory.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79 in com.ahstore.inventory:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #79 in com.ahstore.inventory:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3800)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3976)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2315)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8550)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79 in com.ahstore.inventory:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #79 in com.ahstore.inventory:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79 in com.ahstore.inventory:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.ahstore.inventory.FirstFragment.onViewCreated(FirstFragment.java:35)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.ahstore.inventory.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:75)
        at com.ahstore.inventory.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:69)
        at com.ahstore.inventory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
2022-03-04 16:54:11.474 2392-2392/com.ahstore.inventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3773)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3976)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2315)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8550)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Please post the section of the logcat message when the app crashes

Comment: Logcat has been added, have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment

Comment: the button you want to access in the fragment is declared inside your fragment's layout file and not activity_main.xml, put the button inside the Fragments layout file and it should work. Activities' layout files are different from Fragments'.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few points that will help you understand your issue better

1. Your activity and fragments have their own respective layout files (xmls)
2. View are bound within their layout files. Simply put, if an element with id, say A, is present in `activity_main.xml`, then it can only be accessed when the layout being inflated is `activity_main.xml`. If the contentView of your Activity is `activity_main.xml`, it will be able to access all `View`s inside the layout file.
3. In fragments, the layout is inflated in the `onCreateView` method, which returns the resulting `View` for the Fragment. The `findViewById(id)` method is called against that `View` object. The method will look for the `View` with the given `id` inside that `View` **only**. If it is able to find the `View` it will return it, else it will return `null`. Same goes for finding a `View` inside an `Activity` (you do not need to specify the `View` for an `Activity` as it will automatically reference the layout that is specified in `setContentView`).

Now that we have the above points cleared, we can see the issue that you are facing. Firstly, the buttons with ids `button1` and `button2` are in your `activity_main.xml` layout file. However you are trying to access these from your `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` classes. But your `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` classes have their own layout files which do not have the two buttons. So, when you try to retrieve the buttons (using `findViewById`), it returns `null` because the buttons are not present in the layout. You then try to set a click listener. Since, the button object is `null`, calling any method on it will result in a `Null Pointer Exception` being throw.

We now understand what you are doing wrong. Now, how do we fix this. First you need to understand what it is you want to achieve. In this case I would suggest that you move both buttons to the respective Fragment layouts i.e. the `View` with id `button1` will go to Fragment1 and the `View` with id `button2` will go to Fragment2. This should help resolve the NPE that you are facing.

Still there are some cases where a `Fragment` might want to access a `View` that is present in its parent `Activity`. One of the ways to do this would be to

1. Create a public method in your `Activity` class which returns a `View` with the given id.

   ```
   public View getViewById(int id) {
       return findViewById(id);
   }
   ```
2. Use this method in your `Fragment` by doing so

   ```
   ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getViewById(R.id.button1)
   ```

Other approaches involve using Interfaces which I am sure you will learn about as you continue learning more.

Just to wrap things up, you have two ways to go about fixing your issue. Either move the buttons to the fragment layout files or create a public method to retrieve those views.

Comment: I understood the concept but getParentActivity() is not recongisable.

Comment: Updated answer. The method is `getActivity()`

Comment: Just move the button to the fragment's layout file, please don't access a view from an activity the other way around