# Android Application return NULL

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-audiomanager

Before start let me say I have been searching around for last two days to resolves the Error , did find some usable solution which did't work with me. SO FInally I am posting my code here :

Regarding the code :

I wanted to write an Java application to check a scenario to set the Audio Manager to  MODE_IN_CALL .

code:

```
public class AudioBTActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



 Button Onbutton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.setOn);
    Button offButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.setOff);

    // listen for the button being hit
   Onbutton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this) ;
   offButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
   }

        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.setOff:
                    sAudioActivity();
                    break;
                case R.id.setOn :   
                    AudioActivity();
                }
                    Log.e("AudioActivity() failed",null);

                }

            public void AudioActivity() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AudioManager audioMngr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                boolean isInCall = ((audioMngr.getMode() == AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL));
                if(! isInCall){
                    audioMngr.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                }
            }

        public void sAudioActivity() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AudioManager audioMngr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioMngr.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.AudioBT"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
     <Button
               android:id="@+id/setOn"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:text="ON"
               android:onClick="onClick"
               >

           </Button>

<Button   
               android:id ="@+id/setOff"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="OFF" 
               android:onClick="onClick"
               >
               </Button>
 <Button  
               android:id="@+id/strBT"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:onClick="onClick"
                >
               </Button>
  <Button
               android:id ="@+id/stpBT"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:onClick="onClick"
               >
               </Button>


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AudioBTActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error :
01-31 14:36:53.424: E/AndroidRuntime(1309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AudioBT/com.AudioBT.AudioBTActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Until now I am unable to reach to the reason for crash. an similar thread is here however I am unable to catch the exception in my case 
[findViewById() returns null for custom component in layout XML, not for other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-co)

I have been using the latest version of Android SDK 4.0.3 and Esclipse IDE for Java

any help would be appreciated ,

Thank You

Comment: Is that xml all from your manifest? If so your buttons and things should be declared in a layout file, not in your manifest. I imagine you'd get all sorts of strange errors if you try declaring views in a manifest like that. Also if you can post more of the lines that are underneath the one that says "java.lang.NullPointerException" in your log it will tell you what line in your java file is causing the null pointer

Comment: You shouldn't have any layout XML in your Manifest. It needs to be in its own XML file, in the res folder.

Comment: I am new so my be I can point it wrong. please correct me if I say any in wrong terminolgy.

The xml code I posted is from the AndroidManifest.xml ,which I consider as a Layout file.

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml is not a layout file. If you check in your /res folder you should see main.xml. That's a layout file. Add any new XML layout files to that folder. In your onCreate you can see where it specifies what layout file the Activity is using: setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: Yes, I found it in /res/layout folder and as suggest I modifies main.xml and now I can see the button on my screen. Thank You all:)

Answer (score 1):

Put all this code in res/main.xml

```
   <Button
               android:id="@+id/setOn"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:text="ON"
               android:onClick="onClick"
               >

           </Button>

<Button   
               android:id ="@+id/setOff"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="OFF" 
               android:onClick="onClick"
               >
               </Button>
 <Button  
               android:id="@+id/strBT"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:onClick="onClick"
                >
               </Button>
  <Button
               android:id ="@+id/stpBT"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:onClick="onClick"
               >
               </Button>
```