# Android - findViewById() and dynamically setting ID's

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have a poll of ID's (`ids.xml`), and I assign id's for views I create dynamically. Now my question is pretty simple - assume I create a new view and assign it an id with `setId()` in conjuction with `R.id.uniqueId`. Later on, can I access the view with `findViewById(R.id.uniqueId)`?

If so, what could be the reason it returns null?

Here is a toy example: **UPDATED**

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setId(R.id.mId);
setContentView(l); //i see on screen the views added to 'l'
l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mId); //it returns null :(
```

How come it does not register\map the assgined ID to the view it was assigned?

Comment: Did you find solution of your question? I have same problem with dynamically added view.

Answer (score 2):

Does your desired view have a parent view that you could use to call parent.findViewById on?  That may help narrow your problem down.

One thing I noticed that's missing from your brief example:  you need to make sure you're adding the new LinearLayout to the view hierarchy before you will be able to find it with findViewById:

```
findViewById(R.id.parent).addView(l)
```

You can also use the [hierarchy viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) to take a look and see if everything's being set up properly.

Comment: Thanks for your quit answer. The linear layout is the primary one, i.e. is the first one I dynamically create and assign. So to which parent shall I add it?

Comment: You would say setContentView(l).

Comment: But that's what I did, see my originally post.

Comment: That wasn't there the first time I looked.  :)  However, if you want to be able to refer to l after having set it as the content view, you can call getContentView().  I'm not sure if doing a findViewById will work to find the content view itself (I've never tried) but once you have a reference to it, if you've named child views and added them to it, you should be able to say findViewById with their IDs... I think.

Answer (score 1):

encountered this many times, try cleaning your project by making a clean, Also check [findViewById() returns null for custom component in layout XML, not for other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-co)

Comment: I tried to clean the project, though it did not help, and ``findViewById()`` is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have given us it appears that the view is never added to the Activity's view.  This is necessary as findViewById uses the activity's view as a parent to find a child view with that Id.

If you are creating the view you can always create it as a member variable and refer to it that way if you are going to be adding it to a view at a later time.  Please note that the view must be added *after* the id has been set.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. The linear layout is the primary one, i.e. is the first layout I dynamically create and assign ID. How do I add it to the current running (``this``) activity?