# Inaparent java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm developing an android app and it takes me `java.lang.NullPointerException`and I don't know what can be the reason. In the following lines you will have the `logcat` and the method that causes this crash (line 151).

```
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at tomorrowapps.com.tweeet.Main.DrawViewUp(Main.java:151)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at tomorrowapps.com.tweeet.Main.onOptionsItemSelected(Main.java:340)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:468)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:126)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17359)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5259)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-17 18:56:19.729: E/AndroidRuntime(31291):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here the method that causes the exception (line 151)

```
private void DrawViewUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(adview.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
        drawview.bringToFront();                   //This is line 151
        adview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stroke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rojo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        verde.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        azul.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        negro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (adview.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
        et1.bringToFront();
        adview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stroke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rojo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        verde.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        azul.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        negro.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Also I have a method with all the findViewById that is runned on the onCreate method:

```
private void findViewById() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    views=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.capture);
    drawview=(DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawview);
    adview=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    stroke=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.stroke);
    rojo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rojo);
    verde=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.verde);
    azul=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.azul);
    negro=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.negro);
}
```

So anyone knows why crashes?

EDIT:
I removed all my code, was innnecesary

Comment: `drawviewII.bringToFront()`  - everything you need to know is right here.  `drawviewII` is null.  Where is it initialised?  How does it become in scope for DrawViewUp?  (and please don't name methods beginning with an upper case letter, it's hard to read - see the Java coding standards).  Also, calling your method `findViewById` is confusing and asking for trouble.

Comment: @Simon what about this  `drawviewII=(DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawviewI);`

Comment: @Pragnani  Actually, good point.  If it was out of scope, we'd be looking at a compile time error.

Comment: `findViewById` clearly returns null sometimes.

Comment: But the DrawView its inizialized, I do it on `drawviewII=(DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawviewI);`

Comment: @GabrielEsteban instead of code snippets post your complete code..Are you sure `drawviewII` is not null? Logcat trace clearly says it is null

Comment: Put an `assert` before you use it then test.

Comment: @Pragnani I edited the post, now all the code it's there

Comment: Stop, edit your post again with the actual code that produces the error.  The code has changed, significantly, since you opened the question.  Originally, you had `drawviewII=(DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawviewI);` which looks suspicious (I vs II) and now you have `drawview=(DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawview);`  Post the real code, and the layout XML.

Comment: @Simon Sorry, the actual code is all without I or II is always `drawview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the DrawView class, the second and third constructors don't have in the `super()` the other variables of the constructor as you can see in the following example:

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    public DrawView(Context context) {
    super( context);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super( context, attrs ); //first problem
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super( context, attrs, defStyle ); //second problem
    }

}
```

Solved using:

[findViewById() returns null for custom component in layout XML, not for other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-co)

http://igoesolutions.com/blog/2011/06/20/custom-view-is-not-using-the-2-or-3-argument-view-constructors-xml-attributes-will-not-work/