# Android - findViewById returns null

Tags: android, view, findviewbyid

I'm following an example from a book and I can't understand why findViewById returns null.

This is my activity:

```
package it.mt.compass;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CompassActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        CompassView cv = (CompassView)this.findViewById(R.id.compassView1);

        // this crashes the application
        //cv.setBearing(45);

        // some debug code
        Toast test_result;

        if(cv == null) {
            test_result = Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            test_result.show();
        }
        else {
            test_result = Toast.makeText(this, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            test_result.show();
        }

        // it shows 1
    }
}
```

and this is the res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <it.mt.compass.CompassView 
        android:id="@+id/compassView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Already cleaned (as suggested in other similar topics; what does "Clean" do?) the project with no luck.

Many thanks in advance.
Mirko

As requested, the constructors' code:

```
// Constructors


public CompassView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initCompassView();
    }

    public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        initCompassView();
    }

    public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int defaultStyle) {
        super(context);
        initCompassView();
    }
```

That's the correct version (the problem was I didn't passed the parameters correctly to the superclass constructor):

```
// Constructors


public CompassView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initCompassView();
    }

    public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initCompassView();
    }

    public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int defaultStyle) {
        super(context, ats, defaultStyle);
        initCompassView();
    }
```

Comment: what does the error says?

Comment: Any resource variants of `res/layout-{modifier}/main.xml` without the compassview?

Comment: Try without "this." only  CompassView cv = (CompassView) findViewById(R.id.compassView1);

Comment: @El_Mochiq this code doesn't give errors but if I try to use cv I get a nullpointerexception

Comment: @Iaalto No, it's a very basic app.

Comment: @SandraMladenovic, I tried, nothing changes

Comment: Could you post your `CompassView` constructor code - possibly the attributes are not correctly passed to superclass ctors.

Comment: To answer your "what does "Clean" do?" question, clean deletes the gen folder and recreates the R file from the resource. Hence, it will run through the layout xml files and have the latest list of views/layouts.

Comment: @laalto constructors posted, I copied them from the book

Comment: @laalto ok it was a problem with the constructors; I wasn't good copying from the book :) Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, also upvoted your question since it shows research effort of your own and right off the bat excludes many common pitfalls. That's rare for new SO user questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CompassView` constructor implementation is incorrect. You're not passing the attributes to superclass and hence the `id` is lost.

Change here the superclass constructor invocation

```
public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
```

to `super(context, attrs);`

and

```
public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int defaultStyle) {
    super(context);
```

to `super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);` if the superclass has a ctor that accepts three args. Otherwise just use `super(context, attrs)`. Oh, and rename the arg name from `ats`, even though the name doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you again, this made the job.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse do:

- Projects -> Clean.
- Eefresh your app.
- Run.

this will clear generated old R class.

Comment: Thank for your response. I tried with Clean but it still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I would try closing eclipse completely and then open it again.  I've seen some really bizarre things like this happening.  Another way you can try this is to just add a "textView" and try to do a findById on that and see if it's returning null.  You could be loading the wrong xml view..

ie: your are loading a layout from one directory but it's actually loading a different view in a different directory with the same name...

Comment: I performed a reboot of the machine. It didn't work.

I added a TextView and findViewById works correctly with it.

Answer (score 0):

add `import it.mt.compass.R;`
and try another View, like a Image or TextView instead

Comment: I added a TextView and findViewById works correctly with it, but still no luck with my CompassView

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-co

Comment: Actually it was an error with constructors, I didn't passed all the parameters to the superclass constructor. Thank you!