# findViewById in MainActivity returns null

Tags: android

I have a problem where calling findViewById from MainActivity returns null.
I tried calling findViewById from OnTouchEvent in MainActivity, to make sure that everything has been inflated, but it also returns null.

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.blockslide.blockslide2.StartBlock
    android:id="@+id/mainstartblock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<com.blockslide.blockslide2.EndBlock
    android:id="@+id/mainendblock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StartBlock startBlock = (StartBlock)findViewById(R.id.mainstartblock);
    if(startBlock != null) {
        ((ShapeDrawable) startBlock.getBackground()).getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
}
```

startblock.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/start_end_program_bg"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startblock_textview"
    android:textSize="@dimen/startblock_textview_textsize"
    android:textColor="@color/startblock_textview_textcolor"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

StartBlock.java:

```
public class StartBlock extends RelativeLayout implements Block {
private int blockId;
public StartBlock(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public StartBlock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public StartBlock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context c){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.startblock, this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        blockId = Utils.generateViewId();
    } else {
        blockId = View.generateViewId();
    }
    this.setId(blockId);
}
}
```

start_end_program_bg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ff7777"/>
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ff0000" />
<corners android:radius="100dp"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp"    android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the `StartBlock` in `activity_main.xml:` or in `fragment_main.xml`???

Comment: I don't use fragments here, just one activity, it's in activity_main.xml

Comment: Check if  you have an entry for `mainstartblock` in `R.java` under `id`???

Comment: Yes, from R.java: public static final int mainstartblock=0x7f08003f;

Comment: Make sure you're not using different layouts for different modes, e.g. landscape/portrait.

Comment: I'm not, I don't have a layout-land directory, and I tried switching between landscape and portrait, both show the Toast.

Comment: To narrow the problem down, try with some default view e.g. TextView.

Comment: I tried using a TextView and it's not null. I'll add code for the custom component in the description

Comment: Did u check if the package name com.blockslide.blockslide2.StartBlock is correct? I mean is your StartBlock class is within com.blockslide.blockslide2 ?

Comment: Yes it is within com.blockslide.blockslide2, which confuses me because this is not the first time I've encountered this problem. Most of the time custom components work fine, but occassionally I run into this.

Comment: did u come across this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/1691569/603744 already?

Comment: I did not, but doesn't my code already does that? I have the super(context, attrs); called in the constructor. This is the exact method I used in another project, which worked

Comment: `this.setId(blockId);` why on earth would you do that?

Comment: Oops. I did that because i wanted to add the component dynamically. But then i tested it by stating it in the XML. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and it turns out that changing the view's id, prevents `findViewById` from finding it (pretty obvious now).

Instead use the id that android sets by default, or set the id yourself if one is not present:

```
private void init(Context c) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.startblock, this, true);

    blockId = getId();
    if (blockId == -1) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            blockId = Utils.generateViewId();
        } else {
            blockId = View.generateViewId();
        }
        setId(blockId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right! Silly of me. Thank you