# findViewById() not finding custom view but it exists in layout

Tags: java, android

Somehow my acitivity_main.xml has the view BottomSelectElement (custom view) but I cannot find it in the activity, but I can find anything else.

activity_main.xml (removed unnecessary parts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="it.bachmann.studytimer.ui.MainActivity">

    <!-- THIS IS THE VIEW I CANNOT FIND IN THE MainActivity.java (BottomSelectElement) -->
    <it.bachmann.studytimer.ui.elements.BottomSelectElement
        android:id="@+id/customBottomSelect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my custom view class which is shown perfectly in the activity_main.xml

```
public class BottomSelectElement extends ConstraintLayout {

    private Spinner spinner;

    public BottomSelectElement(Context context) {
        super(context);

            init();
        }

        public BottomSelectElement(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
            super(context);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_select_element, this);
            spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            List<String> categories = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_text, categories);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text_checked);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        public Spinner getSpinner() {
            return spinner;
        }
    }
```

and finally my MainActivity.java which doesn't find the *customBottomSelect*, but it finds anything else.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        BottomSelectElement bottomSelectElement = findViewById(R.id.customBottomSelect);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: bottomSelectElement " + bottomSelectElement); // this returns null, althought it should exist!
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

I restarted Android Studio several times, rebuilt and cleaned it. It just doesn't seem to find this id.

Comment: What is the **exact** error?

Comment: @Konrad can you provide the imports that in both classes

Comment: You have implemented only two Constructors, the third one with parameters (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) is missing. *Just maybe* this is the one which is needed to properly inflate the custom View from xml?

Comment: @0X0nosugar You were absolutely right! The problem was that I wasn't using *super(context, attributeSet)* on the constructor with those parameters. Thanks!

Comment: Well, in this case it wasn't me with the correct idea but @tamtom. (+1 for that!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because in the constructor, you had `super(context)` instead of `super(context, attrs)`.

Makes sense, if you don't pass in the attributes, such as the id, then the view will have no id and therefore not be findable using that id. :-)

Answer ref : [findViewById() returns null for custom component in layout XML, not for other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691569/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-custom-component-in-layout-xml-not-for-other-co)

Comment: I just found out the solution, but thanks! It was exactly as you described it.